# ban.reason is undefined when fetched from audit logs discord.js

Tags: discord.js, audit-logging

ban.reason returns undefined even though there is a reason that was given and it is able to be seen in the server audit log.

this is what i have:

```js
client.on('guildBanAdd', async ban => {
    const fetchedLogs2 = await ban.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        limit: 1,
        type: 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD',
    });

    const banLog = fetchedLogs2.entries.first();
    if (!banLog) return console.log(`${ban.user.tag} was banned from ${ban.guild.name} but no audit log could be found.`);

    const { executor, target } = banLog;

    if (target.id === ban.user.id) {
            console.log(`${ban.user.tag} got hit with the swift hammer of justice in the guild ${ban.guild.name}, wielded by the mighty ${executor.tag}, for "${ban.reason}"`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${ban.user.tag} got hit with the swift hammer of justice in the guild ${ban.guild.name}, audit log fetch was inconclusive.`);
    }
});
```

this is the output:

```
usertag got hit with the swift hammer of justice in the guild guildname, wielded by the mighty moderatortag, for "undefined"
```

how can i fix this error?

Comment: try extracting "reason" as well from banLog `const { executor, target, reason } = banLog` then using ${reason} instead of ${ban.reason}

Comment: The easy way as said by Malik Lahlou above was to use `reason` from `banLog`, but if you want to extract it from the event can you log if `ban.partial` is true or false?